# UIWebView not resizing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I've tried everything I can think of to get my UIWebView to fill the screen automatically on an Iphone 4, 5 and Ipads. I've used auto resizing masks, tried setting the frame programmatically based on the device and still noting has worked.

This is not a scaling problem with the HTML that gets loaded the scroll bars are actually not where they should be.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I know it shouldn't be this difficult.

```
@interface webview ()

@end

@implementation webview

@synthesize weber;

@synthesize suppressesIncrementalRendering;

static NSString* titled;
static NSString* urlholder;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}


-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.weber.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    self.title= titled;


    NSString *fullURL = urlholder;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [weber setSuppressesIncrementalRendering:YES];
    [weber loadRequest:requestObj];

    wasLoaded = NO;
    alertWasShown = NO;
    weber.delegate = self;
}


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    wasLoaded = YES; // Indicates that it finished loading.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}



-(void) setttl: (NSString*) titler
{
    titled= titler;
}

 -(void) setURL: (NSString*) url
 {
    urlholder= url;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code do I see where you are setting the initial frame for the webview. The resizing masks determine how it resizes, but they do not determine the size of the view to start with.

It looks like you are using a xib, try setting the size of the webview to fit correctly in its superview. Then use InterfaceBuilder to set the resizing properties in the Size inspector.

Alternatively, you could set the size programmatically:

```
self.weber.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 700.0);
```

Comment: I tried that and it isn't working. I've tried setting the size to 20, 20 (outrageously small just to see if it worked) and it hasn't changed a thing.

Comment: @centree have you ever found out what the problem was? I have a UIWebView that just won't autoresize. It is defined in IB with the correct springs and struts. Already tried wrapping it inside s UIView, the UIView autoresizes, but the UIWebView doesn't. The only option seems to be manual resize, but I don't like doing that at all.

Comment: @entonio Not using the a webview defined in the storyboard worked for me. Make it all programmatically and it'll work. I believe this has something to do with Authorizing which is turned on by default. Either way doing it programmatically worked well for me.

Comment: @centree thanks! I think I have found the culprit: I'm adding a gradient mask to the webview. I was doing that in `viewDidLoad` and for some reason I think it may hinder further autoresize. And `viewDidLoad` runs before autoresizing is done. So I moved it into `viewDidLayout` and All Is Ok. I disabled rotation because I don't want it; otherwise, I don't know what might happen next, but as it is, I only need the autoresizing to happen once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the superview fills the screen you should assign the `frame` of the `UIWebView` as the `bounds` of its parent in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.weber.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

If your `UIWebView` is being programmatically instantiated the code would look something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.weber = [UIWebView new];
    self.weber.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.weber];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question because I had a similar problem.  What fixed it for me was setting the frame of my UIWebView in `viewDidLayoutSubViews` instead of in `viewDidLoad`.  This was suggested by entonio in a comment on one of the other answers, but I'm putting it here as an answer so it's easier to find if someone else comes along.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that storyboard overrides any code to resize UIWebView. If you're trying to load a dynamic html/css into a UIWebView and it won't resize on Orientation change: Try unchecking the "autolayout" setting.

1. Select .storyboard file
2. Go to identity qand type window (see link snapshot)
3. Uncheck "Use Auto Layout" in Interface Builder Document section.

Source: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1705519